# How to read non English letters in android app

Tags: android

I am facing a problem while trying to read non english characters in android app with something similar to onKeyDown() method. I need to read the letters one by one because i am implementing hangman game for many languages and i have to trigger an action after each entered game.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.v("Hangman", "KEY : " + keyCode);
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
            validateGuess('A');
            break;
```

for english alphabet is ok but only `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_W` is not working, I have no idea why

Any suggestions about how to read german or other nonstandard letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't look at the keyCode, look at the `event.getUnicodeChar()` instead, but have a look at the details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getUnicodeChar()

For example remember that some characters are enteredby first pressing one or more buttons and then another (not talking about shift etc).

Comment: This answer half of the question but i still cant find solution for 'W'. It is not getting nothing event with getUnicodeChar() method ...

Comment: I had some really missed error in my code that was the problem with W... The answer works thank you